# Finite Groups With Exactly Two Automorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Is there an easy way how to characterize the groups with exactly two automorphisms?

I was able to find the following finite groups with exactly two automorphisms: $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $\mathbb{Z}_4$, $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: Let $G$ be a group with automorphism group of order 2. The quotient of $G$ by its center is isomorphic to the group of inner automorphisms, so this has order at most $2$. In particular, it is cyclic and  $G$ is abelian.

The automorphism groups of finite abelian groups are well known and the examples you give are indeed the only ones.

In the infinite case, there is one more example ($\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93782/which-groups-have-precisely-two-automorphisms

Comment: I know that the only groups that have a trivial automorphism are the trivial group and $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But how to prove that the automorphism group of a finite abelian that is not one of $\mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_4, \mathbb{Z}_6$ has at least two non-trivial automorphisms?